# Changing subsequent 1's to 0's in binary data

Tags: arrays, matlab, binary

Hi I have a binary variable (called 'column' size 733x1) and in order to change the 0's in-between where I have 1's to 1's (i.e. 00001110011... to 00001111111...). I am using:

```
column_fill = column;
column_fill(find(column == 1, 1):find(column == 1, 1, 'last')) = 1;
```

I would like to change this to if there is a series of 1's within my variable followed by a series of 5 or more 0's, all further 1's are changed to 0's. [Link to data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ib58auz90eg5f5/data.mat?dl=0). Output (from 000..0001110000011101... to 000..0000000000011111...) Thanks.

Also I would appreciate help with adding an extra part (for somewhere else in my code) if there are single 1's before a group of 1's then change them to 0's. Output (from 000..000111110001 to 000..000111110000). Thank you.

[data 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfk3aycwx2qweoo/column.mat?dl=0)

Comment: Series of '1' is even two '1's together? And as for you second question, the meaning of 'before' seems to be opposite to the first question, since now you read it right to left.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes a series would include two '1' values together. For the second part later in my code I thought also it would be better to read right to left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general way to "ask questions" on your `column100` vector. I make a small set of variables that conclude all information on this vector in a summarized way, that makes all this kind of testing more easy:

First, I create three vectors with the basic information:

```
row_c = fliplr(column100.'); % your questions are "right to left" (The .' is not really needed)
d = diff([row_c(1) row_c]); % find all switches between 1 to 0 or 0 to 1
len = 1:numel(row_c); % make a list of all indices in row_c
idx = [len(d~=0)-1 numel(row_c)] % the index of the end each group
counts = [idx(1) diff(idx)] % the number of elements in the group
elements = row_c(idx) % the type of element (0 or 1)
n_groups = numel(idx) % the no. of groups in the vector
```

the output so far:

```
idx =
   195   199   205   207   235   256   272   733
counts =
   195     4     6     2    28    21    16   461
elements =
     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
n_groups =
     8
```

So we can see the data is made of 8 groups, and, for example, the third group goes from `200:205`, it is a group of `1`, and it has 6 elements.

Now we can perform different tasks with this data:

### Task 1

Our first task was to find groups (`counts`>2) of `1` that are followed by a group of at least 5 `0`:

```
for k = 1:n_groups-1
    % elements(k) --> is this a group of '1'? (it will always be followed by a '0')
    % counts(k)>1 --> is this a series of at least '11'?
    % counts(k+1)>4 --> is it followed by at least '00000'?
    if elements(k) && counts(k)>1 && counts(k+1)>4
        row_c(idx(k)+1:end)=0; % if so, change all following '1' to zeros
        break % and end the loop since all following pairs were removed.
    end
end
```

and we can check and see (by running the code above again without the first line) that now:

```
idx =
   195   199   205   207   235   733
counts =
   195     4     6     2    28   498
elements =
     1     0     1     0     1     0
n_groups =
     6
```

### Task 2

The second task was to "wipe" (change to `0`) all singleton `1`s, if they are followed by a group of at least two `1`s:

```
for k = 1:n_groups-2
    % elements(k) --> is this a group of '1'?
    % counts(k)==1 --> is it single?
    % counts(k+2)>1 --> the next '1' is not single?
    if elements(k) && counts(k)==1 && counts(k+2)>1
        row_c(idx(k))=0; % change the single '1' to '0'.
    end
end
```

The data don't include any single `1`, but if it had this code will change it to `0`.

### Task 3

This is from your [comment to @Tasos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986627/changing-subsequent-1s-to-0s-in-binary-data/39293075#comment65349776_38986974) - change all `0` prior to the last `1` to `1`:

```
for k = n_groups:-1:1
    if elements(k) % is this the last group of '1'?
        row_c(1:idx(k))=1; % change all prior '0' to '1'
    end
end
```

again we can check and see (by running the first block of code above again without the first line):

```
idx =
   272   733
counts =
   272   461
elements =
     1     0
n_groups =
     2
```

now we have only two groups, one of all the `0` after the last `1`, and one for all the rest of the vector that is now changed to `1`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. For a different dataset (I've added above called 'data2') I tried running the code but obtained an error doing so. Received error for 'elements' when using row_c (specifically: 'Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
logicals.').

Comment: @a.kk you right, I have corrected the second line to `d = diff([row_c(1) row_c]);`. Now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably convert to a string sequence and use string /regexp operations. e.g.:

```
c = char(column100'+48);                % convert to string
C = regexp(c, '1.+00000', 'match');     % regular expression.
c2 = strrep(c,C{1},strrep(C{1},'1','0')); % assumes 1 match here, adapt
                                          % appropriately for general case
newcolumn = logical(double(c-48)'); % convert back to logical vector.
```

Similarly you can use a `'010.*'` regexp for the second bit.
If you don't know what regular expressions are, type `help regexp`

Comment: Thanks, is there a way of changing this for when it finds the last '1' to change all previous '0' values to '1'. For example (000...000100100000 to 000...000111111111).